# CSS:using single rule for multiple Ids

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I was using a generic rule for `TH` tag of `Table` but it disturbed every thing. I was using the rule as:

```
th
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #7d7e7d;
}
```

But now I want to specify Ids for a few tables so that it does not effect other tables at all. What I did was:

```
#id1,#id2  th
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #7d7e7d;
}
```

what it did that color spread in  as well. How do I achieve my task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify `th` both times as the comma separates entire selectors:

```
#id1 th, #id2 th
{
    color: #fff;
    background: #7d7e7d;
}
```

Otherwise you're selecting the entire `#id1` as well as just `#id2 th`.

Comment: There's also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A-moz-any if you're fine with experimental features.

Comment: @luiscubal: And that would be `:-moz-any(#id1, #id2) th` or, hopefully/eventually, `:matches(#id1, #id2) th`